# vscode: how to make text after snippet *not* selected?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

When a snippet (for whatever language) is triggered, and the cursor is moved to a tab-stop, the area is "selected" (that is, you are still in "snippet mode" where you can go to another tab-stop). But I would like to get out of this "snippet mode" (e.g not having the area selected after tab-stop), because it suppresses intellisense (the selected area after snippet was triggered accepts anything, so it does no longer suggest intellisense function, variables, etc. Is there a settings in vscode to disable this "selection" after snippet is triggered?

Comment: Disable the setting `Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions`

Comment: @Mark How to go back to snippet mode?

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one tabstop you can use $0 to avoid the "selecttion".

But if you have more than one i don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible.

Snippets often have placeholders such as `${1:name}` to indicate what's expected in that tab stop.

Take this one for example:

```
"JS arrow function": {
    "prefix": "af",
    "body": [
        "const ${1:name} = (${2:props}) => {",
        "\t$3",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Create arrow function"
}
```

Using tab will cycle over $1, $2 and $3, and for $1 and $2 there is a placeholder.

You can omit the placeholders if you want:

```
"JS arrow function2": {
    "prefix": "af2",
    "body": [
        "const $1 = ($2) => {",
        "\t$3",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Create arrow function"
}
```

But instellisense won't work until you press escape.

You can add your own snippets globally or per language if you prefer to customise them and avoid placeholders.

See this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets) for more information.

Comment: I meant just one placeholder, and the exit (without pressing exit -> exit from the `snippet mode` after first tab. That's not possible?